# firestore read and write from another app android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two apps first one is Seller App and second one is Buyer App. I have developed Seller App, it has some information to store about seller and some product Collection, I am using firebase Firestore Database to store info. Now I am developing second Buyer App in which i want to store some info about buyer and also I want to show product collection stored buy seller App in Buyer App.
So, I am totally confused.

> I can access all the data from seller App when i have single Firebase
> project with both seller and buyer app in that firebase project. But
> How can i manage data stored by Buyer App.

**so, I want somehow Buyer app Has permission to Seller App data to read whole data and update only certain data (like review of seller) with another fireabse project in which i can only manage data  stored by Buyer App.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved this problem, now i want some suggestion
heres the code in Buyer App.

```
val option  = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId("project-id-3564") //seller app project id
            .setApiKey("Api_key")// api key of seller app project
            .setApplicationId("1:1234567890")//app id for seller app project
            .build()

        val app = Firebase.initialize(this , option, "secondary")

        val firebase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(app)
        firebase.collection("collection").get().......
```

and also i have to change read write permission to the seller app project database rule

```
match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

to this

```
match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if true;
    }
```

**
Again i got permission denied error

> Which is not recomended.so Now what should i do about giving
> permission

**